# Python Search word contains : in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I try to research if a word exists in a string or not. the problem that the search word contains the character `':'`. the search was not successful even if I used the escape.
In the example the search for the word `'decision :'` return does not exist while the word does exist in the sentence.

Knowing that the search must be exact example: I search the word `'for'` it must return me not exist when the sentence contains the word `'formatted'`.

````
import re
texte ="  hello \n a formated test text   \n decision :   repair \n toto \n titi"
word_list = ['decision :', 'for']
def verif_exist (word_list, paragraph):
   
    exist = False
    for word in word_list:
        exp = re.escape(word)
      
        print(exp)
        if re.search(r"\b%s\b" % exp, paragraph, re.IGNORECASE):
            print("From exist, word detected: " + word)
            exist = True
        if exist == True:
            break
    return exist
if verif_exist(word_list, texte):
    print("exist")
else:
    print("not exist") ```
````

Comment: From the documentation: "`\b` matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters.". There is no word boundary between `:` and a space because both are not part of a sequence of word characters.

Comment: when I search '' decision * " and i change texte ="  hello \n a formated test text   \n decision *   repair \n toto \n titi" with the same regex" / b% exp / b "it works

Comment: Of course it does. You have `" decision * "` and there is a word boundary between the space at the end of this search term and the word `repair` that follows in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states: "\b matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters.". There is no word boundary between : and a space because both are not part of a sequence of word characters.

Maybe you can use either a word boundary or a whitespace in your regular expression.

```
import re

texte = "  hello \n a formated test text   \n decision :   repair \n toto \n titi"
word_list = ['decision :', 'for']


def verif_exist(word_list, paragraph):
    for word in word_list:
        exp = re.escape(word)
        print(exp)
        if re.search(fr"\b{exp}(\b|\s)", paragraph, re.IGNORECASE):
            print("From exist, word detected: " + word)
            return True
    return False


if verif_exist(word_list, texte):
    print("exist")
else:
    print("not exist")
```

That's still not perfect. You might want to take into account what happens if your text ist just `'decision :'`. Here we don't have a word boundary and we don't have a whitespace. We'll have to add a check for the end of the text giving us:

```
    if re.search(fr"\b{exp}(\b|\s|$)", paragraph, re.IGNORECASE):
```

And now you might have to do something similar to the word boundary at the beginning of your regular expression.

Comment: here is what I have with your solution: decision\ :
not exist

Comment: I made a correction now. I used the character group `[\b\s]`, but in a group the `\b` is no longer a word boundary but the backspace character. Changed it to `(\b|\s)`.

Comment: Sorry when i use  if re.search(fr"\b{exp}([\b\s]|$)", paragraph, re.IGNORECASE): it 's not working

Comment: @ElguesmiRamzy You seem to have missed the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Only needed change is removing the second `\b` word boundary you wrap the escaped pattern with. Instead, we positive lookahead to ensure there is a space or end of string after the word. Finally, we capture only the word.

```
import re
texte ="  hello \n a formated test text   \n decision :   repair \n toto \n titi"
word_list = ['decision :', 'for']
def verif_exist (word_list, paragraph):
    for word in word_list:
        exp = re.escape(word)
      
        print(exp)
        if re.search(r"\b(%s)(?=\s|$)" % exp, paragraph, re.IGNORECASE): # remove second word boundary, as we want to match non word characters after the word (space and colon)
            print("From exist, word detected: " + word)
            return True

    return False
if verif_exist(word_list, texte):
    print("exist")
else:
    print("not exist")
```

Comment: Now remove `'decision'` from the word list and try it again. Your code will find the word `for`, but this word is not in the text.

Comment: Sorry, it always returns false for the 'decision:' string while it is exiting

Comment: that is the problem !! it must turn me wrong in I'm looking for 'for'. and with regex r"\b(%s)(?=\s|$)" % exp it return true but the word is not in the text

Comment: With the current approach the simple text `"decision :1"` won't be found.

Comment: @Matthias the search exp "decision :1" won't match "decision :1" in the `paragraph`? Or changing to "decision :1" in the `paragraph` won't match the search exp "decision :"? Because in the second case that should be the expected behavior, the search exp does not match a word in the `paragraph`, it matches part of the word (there is a word character, "1", neighboring it. It would be impossible to match that, and also not match "for".

Comment: @ElguesmiRamzy it does not return `true` on the search exp "for" with that search pattern template. See this running example, which is simply a copy of the code in my answer: https://onlinegdb.com/WoeQnlM86. The output for me is: 
`for \n
not exist`